# Can't download using youtube-dl

Tags: python, ssl, youtube, youtube-dl

I am trying download this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pi3bc9lS3rg which is completely working on Ubuntu server but not on my mac.
I repeatedly get this Warning:

WARNING: unable to set language: 
[youtube] Pi3bc9lS3rg: Downloading webpage

and also following error

ERROR: Unable to download webpage:< urlopen error [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol>

Comment: maybe youtube is blocked in your country.

Comment: It's ok I download via stunnel

Comment: They seemed to have made some modification on the youtube-dl , why dont you go ahead and use the latest. https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/1069

Comment: there are multiple questions here about this error, some of them with accepted answer. Have you read them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to its github, https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/2219, the problem is very likely to be an outdated version of your Python installation.

As a workaround, you can use the .exe instead of the .py, but the solution is just to upgrade your Python.